# Should the SCIM lastModified timestamp be updated when set of groups changes?

Tags: scim, scim2

I'm adding [SCIM](http://www.simplecloud.info/) support to an application which already has a user directory (with support for groups, including nested such etc).

[RFC 6743](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643) defines an attribute of resources called `lastModified`. That this attribute should change when mutable attributes (like `displayName`) of the resource changes is pretty obvious but I'm struggling to determine whether it should change when the `groups` attribute of a resource changes. Such changes does not come from modifying the resource itself, and possibly not even from modifying the groups that the resource is a direct member of (it may be an indirect membership).

So, what do you think? Should the `lastModified` attribute of a resource (user or group in my case) change when the value of the `groups` attribute changes? And should the `lastModified` attribute of a group change if the value of the `members` attribute changes (and if so, even if the change was not through an actual modification of the group itself but rather a result of a member resource being deleted)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in scim mailing list[[1]](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/scim/Yqlf5aqvCNQy-3jKITR48fbRnfQ/), I think lastModified attribute update due to dynamic/indirect changes should not be a part of SCIM implementation. It should be handled at the userstore level.

1. Add a new member to a Group using /Groups endpoint- This may cause to change the groups attribute of a User resource, but it depends on the database query succeeding. Thus, the user's lastModified attribute needs to be updated only after successful Group modification.
2. Delete a user resource cause to change the members attribute of one or more Group resources. Similar to the first scenario, Group resources' would be changed after a successful user deletion database query.